# Retrieving image from Spring Controller to display in a Thymeleaf template

Tags: spring, image, thymeleaf

I am trying to display an image in a Thymeleaf template that is coming from a MySql Database.

Most of it is working but I have a problem with the controller code :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/image/{someId}", produces = {MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPicture(@PathVariable("someId") long someId) throws IOException {

    byte[] imageContent = //Getting the blob element from the Repo through a service     
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=fileName.jpg");
    headers.setContentLength(imageContent.length);        
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(imageContent, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

My code is similar to solutions that ware suggested here (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33840089/3504492) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23441936/3504492)) but my template won't display the image as its content is most probably not valid. If I reach the endpoint directly from the browser, a "filename.jpg" image will download (makes sense following the code above) but that only contains the original name of the image if I open it with a text editor. It's not an image.

There's surely something that I am missing in the configuration of the ResponseEntity. Do you perhaps have some documentation I could read about the process because I don't understand fully what is going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot setContentType is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708935/spring-boot-setcontenttype-is-not-working)